# Getting best latitude longitude response form various ip database internet services

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I have a website that checks the users ip address on many online databases, and gets responses with latitude and longitude.

Here is an example:

```
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [statusCode] =&gt; OK
            [statusMessage] =&gt; 
            [ipAddress] =&gt; 37.6.226.186
            [countryCode] =&gt; GR
            [countryName] =&gt; GREECE
            [regionName] =&gt; ATTIKI
            [cityName] =&gt; ATHENS
            [zipCode] =&gt; -
            [latitude] =&gt; 37.9795
            [longitude] =&gt; 23.7162
            [timeZone] =&gt; +03:00
        )

    [1] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [ip] =&gt; 37.6.226.186
            [country_code] =&gt; GR
            [country_name] =&gt; Greece
            [region_code] =&gt; 
            [region_name] =&gt; 
            [city] =&gt; 
            [zipcode] =&gt; 
            [latitude] =&gt; 39
            [longitude] =&gt; 22
            [metro_code] =&gt; 
            [areacode] =&gt; 
        )

    [2] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [source] =&gt; smart-ip.net
            [host] =&gt; 37.6.226.186
            [lang] =&gt; en
            [countryName] =&gt; Greece
            [countryCode] =&gt; GR
            [city] =&gt; 
            [region] =&gt; 
            [latitude] =&gt; 39.0000
            [longitude] =&gt; 22.0000
            [timezone] =&gt; 
        )

)
```

I have noticed that sometimes 1 response might be totally off showing an irrelevant place hence a bad latitude + longitude.

How would you resolve an issue as this?
perhaps loop through the results and check closest values and then pick 1 response?
I'm not sure about this since I'm junior in php.
Any guidance or reference will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for you to determine which coordinates are the best. Any value might be correct, even the one that seems to be irrelevant. More likely, none of the values is correct.

If you want to pick a value, pick one at random. It's as good as any other.

The other option is to apply some algorithm to all the values (e.g. the average of the ones in the city with the most records or the average of the ones where the most records fall into a 10 mile radius).

Comment: I was thinking to make a loop and if for example 2 results have latitude and longitude close to one another then disregard the 3rd result

Comment: I would first define what the algorithm should do (see my examples for how to formulate that) and only after that figure out how to implement it using loops and whatever. You will have to experiment if you want better results than what a single service gives you.